# Generating multiple plots according to some rules

Tags: plotting

Let us assume I have two lists of the same lenght and in the form:

```
mesh ={{0.1, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.8}, {0.1, 1.3}, {0.6, 0.3}, {0.6, 0.8}, {0.6,1.3}, {1.1, 0.3}, {1.1, 0.8}, {1.1, 1.3}, {1.6, 0.3}, {1.6, 0.8}, {1.6, 1.3}};

colors={1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
```

I'd like to make a `ListPlot` with the values form `mesh` and make every point green if the corresponding point in `colors` is `1` or elese red. If it helps you can assume that there exists a function `f` that for every element of `mesh` gives the corresponding element `color`.

My idea was to generate all the plots separately and save them into some variable names and then just use `Show` to display them all at once. I tried implementing this with

```
Do[
 If[f[k] == 1,
  Symbol["plot" <> ToString[Flatten[Position[mesh, k]][[1]]]] = 
   ListPlot[{k}, PlotStyle -> Green],
  Symbol["plot" <> ToString[Flatten[Position[mesh, k]][[1]]]] = 
   ListPlot[{k}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {k, mesh}]
```

but this gives me the error

```
Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[plot1] is Protected.
```

and in general seems like a rather cluncky methode to get this done... Can anybody suggest a (more sophisticated) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style) wrapper to control the colors:

```
ListPlot[Thread @ Style[mesh, Lookup[{1->Green, 0->Red}, colors]]]
```

[image]

Or you can segregate the points using [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
ListPlot[
    Lookup[
        GroupBy[Thread[{mesh, colors}],Last->First],
        {1,0}
    ],
    PlotStyle->{Green,Red}
]
```

[image]

Or you can use [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point) with a [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors) option in [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics):

```
Graphics[
    {
    PointSize[Medium],
    Point[mesh, VertexColors -> Lookup[{1->Green, 0->Red}, colors]]
    },
    Axes->True, AxesOrigin->{0,0}
]
```

[image]